# How do I fix blurry font in a PDF?

Tags: pdf, fonts

I have a PDF file that looks like this (I've selected a chunk to show the difference)

[image: shitty pdf]

As you can see, the text is too bold and hard to read, but I can see an underlying layer, which is normal font face. How do I remove the top layer, leaving only the copy-able text?

Comment: Looks like this is a scan and the blurry font is coming from the original image, while what you are selecting is the invisible layer of text that searchable scans get after being OCRd.

Comment: @Edi, yeah! How do I remove the stuff from the original image?